# Error while installing postgreSQL database

Tags: mysql, django, postgresql

I have to change my databasefrom MySQL to postgreSQL in django. But postgreSQL is not installing .

Error while installing postgreSQL using commands-

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get purge postgresql*
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get install postgresql
```

At terminal-

```
(jango)dc@dc-comp-4:~/website$ sudo apt-get install postgresql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 postgresql : Depends: postgresql-9.3 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

but its not working.how can i do this.and what changes i have to made. Plz help

Comment: I'm not an expert on debian-like distrib, but perhaps you have to try first to fix your broken package using: `sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update`

Answer (score 0):

`aptitude` might be able to resolve this issue. It's a more sophisticated dependency management tool than `apt-get`.

You may install it with apt-get:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

You may use `aptitude` to install `postgresql`

```
sudo aptitude install postgresql-9.3
```

If `aptitude` encounters any problems it automatically devises a possible solution to install this package. Be aware that aptitude might suggest remove conflicting packages. So if you get prompted by `aptitude` please read the prompt carefully.